# "Man" is to "womanizer" as "woman" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, gender-politics

What's the feminine version of *womanizer*?

Comment: I don't agree that _bitch_ would be a very good candidate. When used to describe a woman (mind you, some consider this an offensive term), it's used to denote a quick temper and irritable demeanor, more so than the female equivalent of _womanizer_.  (I realize you're asking for better alternatives, but I just wanted to mention that I don't think _bitch_ fits.)

Comment: I'd say "nymphomaniac."

Comment: You would think that a skirt-chaser, being a lover of women (or Highlanders :), would be said to engage in *philogyny*, but instead he’s known as a *philanderer* (< Greek *ϕίλανδρος*) — which while at first glance would be just the word you’re looking for, certainly is not. Would *flirt* or *coquette* work better for you, or do you need something wicked? The OED says that in early use, being a *vamp* was a notion that “ranged widely from gallantry, wantonness, or immodesty, to pretty pertness”.

Comment: Well, if she’s young enough, we have Nabokov to thank for calling her a ***Lolita***, who is a barely pre-post-pubescent kind of *seductress*. I think she may mature into a *succubus* of sorts.

Comment: @HaLaBi: Not my downvote, although I wonder if your use of the b-word led to some downvotes, partly because some deem it offensive, and partly because it's not a very good fit.

Comment: Your title and question are a bit contradictory.  Reading the title, I inferred that the question was a man womanizes a female so what do you call a female that womanizes a male.  However, the question implies what is a woman that womanizes; I wasn't aware that womanizing was gender specific.  As opposed to (what the title led me to believe the question was)... manizing?

Comment: Just to clarify, a woman could be a womaniser. Note that I've used the correct english spelling. I assume you want a term for one with many male partners? Perhaps you could expand the question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

*Man-eater* and *vamp* are a little bit "slangy" compared to

> **seductress** [- a woman who seduces someone, esp. one who entices a man into sexual activity](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=seductress&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=A3nCT6WuG8GV8QPKvdyECw&ved=0CF4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5c37ccd3c94b846&biw=1157&bih=867)

Per Neil's comment to the question itself, *bitch* isn't really relevant to the meanings involved here.

Per comments/discussion below, it's probably impossible to come up with a "feminine version of *womanizer*" that ***only*** switches the gender without implying other differences. Language reflects social attitudes, biology, etc., so even a structurally trivial distinction such as *seducer/seductress* unavoidably entails gender-based preconceptions that OP is probably seeking to avoid.

Comment: To me, one of the key facets of a womanizer is that he has relations with *many* women. Although *seductress* fits in some ways, couldn't it also be used to describe a woman who pursues a man on only one occasion?

Comment: @Cameron: I think that would be a somewhat sexist interpretation - would you call a man who only pursued one woman on one occasion a *womaniser*? Of course not. So why label a woman by "one-time-only" behaviour? Real seductresses often make a career of it as [golddiggers](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=gold+digger&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=YK7CT7SsAs608QPf2anYCg&sqi=2&ved=0CF8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5c37ccd3c94b846&biw=1157&bih=867)

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think it would be out of place to describe a woman who has seduced a man, even just once, as a *seductress*. If a man seduced a woman only once, I wouldn't call him a womanizer, but I would certainly call him a *seducer*, so I don't think it's a particularly sexist interpretation.

Comment: @Cameron: Hmm. It sounds like a "label" to me. If I happened to know it was the woman, not the man or mutual, *and* if I happened to be discussing such delicate matters with another party (God forbid! :) I think I'd probably say *"she made the running"*, *"she was up for it"*, or *"she was all over him"*. What she did, not who she is. Unless she's a right slag - but then it wouldn't be a "one-off", would it?

Comment: I prefer _man-eater_ to _seductress_.  A seductress is merely good at creating sexual desire in men. A man-eater uses men for her own desires without much care for any harm she may be doing to the men.  This is more analogous to _womanizer_ than the other options are.

Comment: Isn't 'womanizer' slangy too?  (a sincere question, I'm not an english speaker)

Comment: @Sebastián Grignoli: I wouldn't say *womaniser* is particularly "slangy". It's a neutral/slightly disapproving idiomatic term - alongside *lady's man* for "approving", and *lecher* for "strongly disapproving".

Comment: _Seductress_ still doesn't ring right to me.  A womanizer is one who _engages in numerous casual sexual affairs with women_, while a seductress is _a woman who seduces someone, esp. one who entices a man into sexual activity_ (NOAD). A serial nature is implied with the former word, not necessarily so in the latter.  Not that this word isn't a good one to consider – it is – but if I saw "**man : womanizer :: woman : seductress**" as the answer on a standardized test, I'd vehemently vote to throw the question out ~ which goes to show how hard it is to find just the right word. Great question.

Comment: I guess this depends on your point of view. I would personally say that if "man-eater" and "vamp" are 'slangy' then you're setting a pretty low bar on what you count as being slang. On the other hand, for me "seductress" would be over literary for most contexts.

Comment: @J.R.,Neil: I pretty much agree with everything you guys say, but at the end of the day there isn't really an "exact" female equivalent, because our language and culture make such strong distinctions between men and women. Particularly in such matters as sexuality itself - which is assumed to be "inbuilt" and natural to men, but must somehow be part of some higher goal in women.

Comment: I guess you could try `Serial seductress`, if you want to get a bit closer...

Answer (score 46):

***Man-eater*** is one term sometimes used.

> [INFORMAL] a dominant woman who has many sexual partners
> [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=man-eater%20define)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-eater) Man-eater is something else ;)

Comment: Yes, as a biological term it means something else. Sometimes words have more than one meaning. Shocking fact: Wikipedia doesn't contain all of the knowledge in the universe.

Comment: I think "man-eater" fits perfectly.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/man-eater
4. (Informal) a woman with many lovers

Comment: @HaLaBi Their definition includes cougars…

Comment: Based on my limited experience as non-native speaker, *man-eater* sounds somewhat more disparaging than *womanizer". But it is nevertheless the best option I see.

Comment: @Gorpik: You're correct that man-eater is a bit more disparaging than womaniser; it implies *predatory* as well as *sexual*.  However, it's probably as close as you can get.  Gender biases in English mean that there often isn't an exact equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

You could say **vamp**.

> "A woman who attracts men sexually, then seduces and exploits them" (Chambers)

Comment: One problem with _vamp_ is that a significant part of the meaning is that she is using her sexuality to gain non-sexual benefits.

Comment: @mgkrebbs. My dictionary (Websters 2nd edition) has "A woman who uses her charms  .. to gain admiration or attention from the opposite sex."  No mention of exploitation.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: I checked a few dictionaries – I couldn't find any mention of "non-sexual benefits", although I did find the notion of "exploiting" a man to "get what she wants." But, when you get right down to it, isn't that also what a womanizer does?

Comment: @J.R. "How can men possibly use sex to get what we want? Sex *is* what we want!" Dr Frasier Crane.

Answer (score 11):

One that comes to mind is **man-chaser**. Another common slang term with a similar meaning is **boy-crazy**, though it doesn't have the same sexual connotation.

A natural follow-up question is, "why is there no such word as *manizer*?" There is a [language log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2367) post that discusses the coinage of this word, with the main argument against *manizer* being the awkwardness of the monosyllabic root with the *-ize* suffix. The comments suggest a number of interesting alternatives.

Comment: Given that gay men can certainly be ***boy-crazy*** — and often are :) — I wonder whether gay women can be ***womanizers***?

Comment: @tchrist: the OED would infer so, via its parenthetical statement: _A person (typically a man) who engages in casual sexual or romantic encounters with women_

Comment: @J.R. "casual .. encounters" - that seems a bit kind to me. I think *womaniser* definitely carries connotations of exploitation or manipulation. Or maybe just a level of emotional detachment. I'm aware I'm arguing with the OED here, not you.

Answer (score 10):

*Wanton* is probably the closest term.  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/WANTON?s=t) define the word as "a lascivious person, especially a woman."  There's a good discussion on "What is the female equivalent of 'philanderer'? on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-female-equivalent-of-philanderer), and it explores the complex nuances involved in comparing the sexes in this regard.

Personally, I like *female Don Juan*, a term applied to Carla Bruni in [a recent biography](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/world/carlia-bruni-a-female-don-juan-says-unflattering-new-biography-of-frances-first-lady/story-e6frg6so-1225919213271).  The term coveys a sense of direct power and control that is typically is missing in describing women who have multiple sexual partners.

Comment: Not too sure that *Doña Juana* would work for most people.

Comment: @tchrist: Donna Juanita?

Comment: @J.R. Don Juan & Doña Juanita *vs* Don Giovanni & Donna (whatever the female Italian is for Giovanni)

Comment: @tchrist -- "Juana" and "Giovanna", respectively are the female forms in Spanish and Italian.

Answer (score 9):

Please excuse me if you find these terms profane but, my grandmother would refer to woman who chases men as a *slut*, although this is sometimes used to describe a girl as dirty or messy. I do recall a man using the term to describe another who was especially open and active in his choice of bedfellows.

I've often heard the rather coarse term *slag* used as slang but I would suggest this reflects negatively on the user.

I assume these both share a common route with the old fashioned term [*slattern*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/slattern) which in turn leads me to consider *harlot*, *brazen hussy* or *trollop*.

Comment: And note how all of them have negative connotations, unlike the term “womaniser” which, if anything, has a positive (admiring) note. Which really says a lot about our society …

Comment: @KonradRudolph, totally agree, all these terms are traditioanlly derogatory and while womanizing is not necessarily encouraged it is often deemed more acceptible. Certainly in eighteenth century england women were still burned at the stake for Petit Treason. A history I found truly bizarre for a "civilized" society, not dissimilar to contemporary stonings. http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1519461

Comment: Nothing wrong with `slag` - in the UK its an often-used term although more as vernacular than in high-falutin' circles. In the US I understand the equivalent is `ho`, a truncation of `whore`which again in the UK is still in use amongst people of a certain age and social class.

Comment: @Konrad: *Slut* is in fact often the word that comes to mind; the double-standard you mention has been a point of contention for some time. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuity): _Feminism has traditionally argued that there is a significant double standard between how men and women are judged for promiscuity. Historically, stereotypes of the promiscuous woman have tended to be negative, such as "the slut", while male stereotypes have been more varied, some expressing approval, such as "the stud", while others imply societal deviance, such as "a womanizer"._

Comment: @J.R. I’m not sure what you mean by “point of contention”. Surely the argument is more or less universal in modern societies, not just among feminists?

Comment: @Konrad: I was merely referring the sense of frustration that often accompanies the age-old question: "Why is it considered negative when a woman does it, and not necessarily so the other way around?" I think we're in agreement.

Comment: @J.R. You apparently mean "concern", not "contention" -- the latter is simply the wrong word for the meaning you tried to convey.

Comment: @Jim: You're probably right. Let me try this: _this double-standard has annoyed/bothered/irked some people for a long time_.  That's all I was trying to say. :^)

Comment: 'Slattern' is not an archaic term and does not have sexual connotations, a slattern is a woman of slovenly habits who does not do her housework properly like a good woman should! I'm being ironic of course, before anyone leaps to the attack.

Comment: @Mynamite, I agree, `slattern` is not archaic and I've corrected. However, I disagree with your assertion concerning sexual connotations. I think this dates back to a time when it was considered more impolite to directly reference anothers sexual activity. In the feminine case, a description of messiness or untidiness, has been used to imply a "lack of moral rigour" or promiscuity. Likewise, the modern term `dirty` can be used in both sexual and non sexual contexts to describe both men and women. Its meanings can be varied and not limited to cleanliness, trustwothiness and promiscuity.

Comment: Everyone here in the comments is talking as if `slut\slag\ho` is an acceptable equivalent to `womaniser`, and then bemoaning how much the double standard says about society. I say `slut` is no sort of equivalent. It's entirely different in its connotations. Also it's not unheard of to call a man a `slut` (although many definitions explicitly say "woman"). `Man-eater` or `vamp` (in other answers) are much closer. Still slightly more derogatory, but for those it would at least be legitimate to discuss how they reflect on society.

Comment: @RobinWinslow, I refer to the term "`man-slut`" in the answer, the term could be applied to any man, whatever the sex of his partner(s). I don't agree that `vamp` is indicative of any level of promiscuity, or even a promiscuous intent. A lady could be a celebate vamp. I would agree that `Man-eater` is probably the best analouge of the answers and have already voted for it accordingly, it idicates a level of female dominance in the partnerings which seems correct. The subjective offensiveness of any term says as much about the terms user and the offendedee as the object of any statement.

Comment: "I say slut is no sort of equivalent. It's entirely different in its connotations." -- A womanizer is "a promiscuous heterosexual man". It has the same *denotation*, with gender changed, as "slut", and thus is a "sort of equivalent".

Comment: _Also it's not unheard of to call a man a slut..._  Borrowed term.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest "loose woman" as an alternative to the very derogatory term "slut." Although "loose woman" also carries a sermonizing attitude, neither is such an implication entirely absent from "womanizer." The latter is certainly not a term of praise.

Were it not for the usual sexual asymmetry present in our language and culture, "loose man" would be a reasonable synonym for "womanizer."

I also agree with the suggestion above that "man-chaser" is a good equivalent, and probably better than "loose woman."

Answer (score 8):

'Siren' carries a connotation that the object of her attractions is doomed to disaster.

Answer (score 2):

**floozy**

> A girl or a woman who has a reputation for promiscuity.

Answer (score 0):

> **Slut**. 
>   [***Slut***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slut?s=t): Disparaging and Offensive. a sexually promiscuous woman, or a woman who behaves or dresses in an overtly sexual way.

Not the nicest or most proper word, but IMO definitely the most accurate.

> Promiscuous

might not be a bad choice either. Although it tends to be gender neutral, it seems to be used more commonly with reference to women.

[***promiscuous***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/promiscuous?s=t): *Characterized by or involving indiscriminate mingling or association, especially having sexual relations with a number of partners on a casual basis.*

Comment: @ab2 _Cougar_ : http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cougar
Informal. **an older woman who seeks sexual relationships with much younger men**;   _much, much less insulting than calling a woman a slut_ that's due to gender roles, not the word.

Comment: Why do you simply repeat what you said before, after I cited the dictionary definition of _cougar_, and explained the fallacy in your logic? If you want to make a meaningful contribution, refute what I said.

Comment: *slut* was already [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69185/68817), but *promiscuous* wasn't. - *cougar* denotes old age, and from what I've been told, there's no worse way (other than "fat") to describe a woman. If I were a cougar, I think I'd take *slut* as a compliment, way before I was cool with you calling me a cougar.

Answer (score -1):

What about wench?

> wench  (wnch) n.
>   1. A young woman or girl, especially a peasant girl.
>   2. A woman servant.
>   3. A wanton woman. intr.v. wenched, wench·ing, wench·es To consort or engage in sex with wanton women. Used of a man.

Comment: *Wench*, historically, marks standing rather than behaviour.

Comment: Expand your answer with a dictionary definition instead of adding junk to reach the 30 character limit.

Comment: Even to the extent that `wench` does imply sexual behaviour, it ties that behaviour implicitly to the lower classes. `Womaniser`, on the other hand, is quite likely to be applied to more upper class men.

Comment: What about it? It obviously is not the correct answer.