# “Woman” is to “coquette” as “man” is to what?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language, analogy

*Wiktionary* reads:

> **coquette:** a *woman* who flirts or plays with *men*’s affections.

Is there an English word which fits the following definition?

> **???:** a *man* who flirts or plays with *women*’s affections.

Comment: `woman : coquette :: man : pussette`, or maybe *pussito* for a more masculine yet diminuitive term

Comment: For use, I recommend @coleopterist's answer, 'philanderer', over 'coquet' as it is still current.

Comment: @StoneyB So to you a philanderer is a mere flirt? Really?

Comment: Per answers and comments to [“Man” is to “womanizer” as “woman” is to what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129), language isn't inherently symmetrical about the "axis" of gender. For reasons of social attitudes, biology, etc., the concept of "male equivalent to coquette" is probably bordering on meaningless.

Comment: Doesn't the term 'flirt' work for males?

Comment: @FumbleFinger Sexism and hypocrisy become clearer and more obtrusive in your second comment. Sorry, but I must say this!

Comment: @Xavier Vidal Hernández: I don't see why you think just my *referring* to manifest gender asymmetry in the English language makes *me* sexist. How do you explain why the word *woman* derives from *wife-man*?

Comment: General Reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr:** So long as you are content with historical terms rather than merely contemporary ones, the precise word you are looking for is ***coquet***.

Here’s why.

---

The OED says that a ***coquette*** is first:

> **1**. A woman (more or less young), who uses arts to gain the admiration and affection of men, merely for the gratification of vanity or from a desire of conquest, and without any intention of responding to the feelings aroused; a woman who habitually trifles with the affections of men; a flirt. In early use the notion ranged widely from gallantry, wantonness, or immodesty, to pretty pertness.

Curiously, it also provides a later subsense:

> **c**. **male coquette:** = **coquet** B 1

Where we learn that the sense **B 1** of ***coquet*** is

> **B.** *sb.* **1.** A man who from vanity or selfish motives aims at making himself generally attractive to the other sex; a male flirt; a ‘lady-killer’.

Whence we learn of this curious etymology:

> a. Fr. *coquet*, orig. sb., dim. of *coq* cock, in reference to the strutting gait and amorous characteristics of the cock; hence ‘a beau’, and in the fem. *coquette* ‘a belle’; also as adj. ‘forward, wanton, gallant’: cf. **cock** *v.<sup>1</sup>*, also **cockish**, **cocky** *a*., and **cocket** *a*., which is prob. the same word in an earlier stage of meaning. In later use, the adjective in English became inseparably blended with the attributive use of the sb., to which also it became entirely assimilated in sense. The sb. was, as in Fr., formerly used of both sexes, and in both spelt *coquet*; but in the 18th c. the 
>   fem. became *coquette* after Fr., and the masculine became obsolete.

The pronunciations given for both are identical.

Comment: Or simply *cock*.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps one of the following may apply:

> - *rake*
> - *ladies’ man*
> - *player* (urban and somewhat slangy)
> - *Don Juan*
> - *Lothario*
> - *Casanova*
> - *wolf* (less suave)
> - *womanizer*

Answer (score 4):

The term *flirt* works generically for both genders.

Answer (score 3):

For a word that applies solely to men, [philanderer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/philanderer) is usually a good fit. You can usually find such terms by simply [using a thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/coquette).

Comment: I think this is completely misleading. A *philanderer* generally means a man who habitually seeks **sex** as the goal for his interactions with women. A *coquette* specifically means a *flirt, prick-teaser*, who likes the "social" attention of men, but has no intention of allowing this to lead to actual sexual congress.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Bernard Shaw, explaining the title of his play The Philanderer to his Swedish translator: "A philanderer is a man who is strongly attracted by women. He flirts with them, falls half in love with them, makes them fall in love with him, but will not commit himself to any permanent relation with them, and often retreats at the last moment if his suit is too successful . . ."

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED's definition, by the way, is "One who philanders; a male flirt."

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers: *Philanderer*'s strongest connotations are of a man who is habitually sexually unfaithful, not just flirtatious.