# An English expression for 'femme fatale'

Tags: expressions

*Femme fatale*, meaning "an attractive and dangerous woman", is a French expression which has become part of the English language roughly since the beginning of the 20th century. Is there another English word or idiomatic expression which conveys the same meaning?

Comment: As you say, *femme fatale* (not *fatal*, by the way), has become part of the English language. As such, the English word or idiomatic expression for *femme fatale* is, rather unsurprisingly, *femme fatale*. It is also the *only* expression that means that. Everything else will mean something ever-so-slightly different. That's the whole point of borrowing a word in the first place: because you do *not* already have it.

Comment: "Rabbit cooker"  : )

Comment: What's wrong with *Femme Fatale*? We have been importing French words and concocting (and cockneying) french words for centuries. Why make an exception?

Comment: **Mata Hari** used to be used for such, but too much time has passed since World War One. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mata_Hari

Comment: There's **Black Widow**, though this usually applies to women who marry and then kill off their husbands (in order to gain any insurance payoffs or such).

Comment: This is related and mostly same answers are there: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/feminine-equivalent-for-casanova

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/femme%20fatale

Comment: So is the whole point of the question to use a word or phrase of wholly Anglo-Saxon origin (no loan words or imports)?

Comment: The question could have been (re)phrased as: What were fascinating and manipulative women called before *femme fatale* was loaned to the English language? A bit late now...

Comment: You are right... The most popular answer insist on the fact that it is an English expression. Anyway I'm pleased  that the issue has received a lot of attention !!

Comment: "*Jezebel*" is the other English word that I have heard most often to describe the same thing.

Comment: @Jack, so something like "beautiful, but deadly" (if the reader already knows you're talking about a woman, "a beautiful, but deadly, woman" otherwise)? Being English, those were probably loan words at _some_ point, but well absorbed by now.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The English expression for *femme fatale* is **femme fatale**.  No joke.

Comment: You can choose any of [*courtesan, temptress, vamp, attractive woman, coquette, dangerous woman, deadly lady, deadly woman, enchantress, enticing woman, flirt, seductress,
siren*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/femme%20fatale) if you insist, but in all cases you lose the cultural ties-in that *femme fatale* provies.

Comment: Some of those (like "dangerous woman") mean the same thing. But many in this list are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 35):

Consider [*vamp*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vamp) and *maneater*.

> [vamp](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vamp): a seductive woman who uses her sensuality to exploit men; femme fatale

A maneater is the female equivalent of a player. An irresistible woman who chews and spits out men after using them for some sort of gain -- be it sexual, financial, or psychological.

> [maneater](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maneater): *Slang*. femme fatale

Alternately, *mantrap* might also fit for what you're looking for.

> [mantrap](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/man-trap): *Slang*. a woman considered dangerously seductive and scheming; femme fatale

Comment: Except that one's a shortening of *vampire*, which was borrowed from French as well, so you're back at square one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, if everything descending from another language is an invalid answer, then it would appear no answer on this site would be valid. Further, the English "vampire" may have skipped French "vampyre" entirely and come straight from German "vampir." There are also many other languages with a similarly-spelled/pronounced word with approximately the same meaning, so calling it a word borrowed from French is a bit shaky.

Comment: @BrianS Unlike "femme fatale," "vamp" is used as an anglicism in France. http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vamp

Comment: @BrianS I think you miss the point. Everything descending from another language is *not* an invalid answer on this site. However, everything descending from another language *is* an invalid answer *to this particular question*. I did not invent this restriction, the OP did. I am actually very much arguing the restriction makes no sense whatsoever. (As to *vampire*, I know the origin is disputed, but I am not buying for a second that English adds *-e* to German words like that. It simply does not. That final E is a dead giveaway we got it from the French, IMHO.)

Comment: @BrianS According to Wikipedia, vampires were made up by the writer John Polidori (not Bram Stoker, btw), which would make the word 'vampire' originally an English word.

Comment: @poepje, John Polidori's _Vampyre_ popularized the modern concept of the vampire (mythical creature), but it was very much **not** the origin of the word.

Comment: Which name came first, the animal species _vampire bat_, or the monster _vampire_?

Answer (score 16):

You could use the word [*siren*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_%28mythology%29), based on Greek mythology. The Sirens were beautiful women who lured sailors into danger.

Comment: Thus replacing French with Greek.

Comment: @bmargulies Where do you think most English words come from? You would have to work hard to restrict answers to words of Germanic origin.

Comment: Of course. I'm tweaking the OP's original desire to escape French.

Comment: @bmargulies I can't speak for the OP, of course, but I don't think the goal is to completely *escape* loanwords, but only ones that *shout* their loanwordness - such as often being written in italics.

Comment: The word *siren* is English; the Greek word it derives from is *seiren*, Σειρήν.

Comment: "Siren" is an utterly English word.

Answer (score 16):

Try *Delilah, enchantress* or *temptress.* If she is a spymaster's decoy, she could also be a *honey pot.* The less flattering term *bunny-boiler* also exists, after actress Glenn Close's character in the 1987 movie *Fatal Attraction*.

Comment: Delilah is good.

Comment: Agreed on the "temptress". "Bunny-boiler", however, is more of "insane ex".

Comment: Fantastic point on **honey pot** in certain situations.  Good one.

Answer (score 5):

Lots of words and expressions in foreign languages have no direct equivalent in English, and none have been devised, simply because it is easier to use the non-English. The foreign phrase conveys an established meaning, which any attempt at translation might lose.

See Oxford Dictionary of foreign phrases http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/foreign-words-and-phrases.

It translates *femme fatale* roughly as 'seductive woman', or 'disastrous woman'.

It is usual when using such expressions to put them in italics.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps **[seductress](http://www.yourdictionary.com/seductress)**

> a woman who seduces, esp. one who seduces a man sexually

Answer (score 4):

Succubus and black widow comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

The first word that comes to my mind is "vixen", which seems to capture both the danger and seduction of femme fatale.

Comment: I also considered "vixen" as an answer. But, after looking up the definition online, I had like, you know, a change of mind. ;-)

Comment: A vixen is a female fox.

Answer (score 3):

The term I would use is **black widow.** The original, a spider, eats her mate after copulation.

Comment: A "black widow" is a woman who marries and then kills her husband(s), which is more specific than "femme fatale".

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised nobody has suggested *cougar*, although that has more of a "dirty old man" connotation. Perhaps *barracuda*, which I have always interpreted to mean a cougar who is looking for someone her own age.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Honeypot or Honeytrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot).

Answer (score 1):

This is a fascinating question.  I note that nobody has referred to the phrase as clearly having TWO words  Following this format, a translation would be "dangerous woman".
Femme = woman
Fatale = fatal, but is not meant to be so drastic, so dangerous is closer to what is implied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe *vamp*, a shorten form of vampire used exclusively to describe females is perhaps the closest word that is I believe considered anglicized. Though its usage is fairly rare outside novels and movies, so I don't know how the general populace would recognize it.

*Sharon Stone* - might be a better choice, but not quite *idiomatic*, for a younger pop-culture obsessed audience.

Explanation: The movie [Basic Instinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Instinct).

Or perhaps [Nikita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikita_%28film%29).