# What do you call a woman who actively chases men?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not looking for any derogatory term, but for something that the woman herself would say

Example:

> He was a good guy. Not sure why I was so sure of that. Maybe it was a
>   skill that I developed when I was a [...].

Comment: Are *instincts* developed?

Comment: Downvoting because you're getting into  subjective territory here.

Comment: @TimRomano You're right. I meant "skill".

Comment: Did you mean 'a skill' and not 'an skill'?

Comment: The ability to *suss* whether a person is "nice" or a "creep", is I believe sensory, tactile, based on instinct not a skill you can develop or sharpen. Experience will fine tune it, undoubtedly, but it's that extra something which women naturally have, a gut feeling, if you like. As for a woman who chases a man, there are ONLY derogatory terms. :) Women weren't supposed to hunt, men were. And this question, worded differently, has been asked before!

Comment: related (possible duplicates): [**Feminine equivalent for Casanova**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/feminine-equivalent-for-casanova) and **[“Man” is to “womanizer” as “woman” is to what?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/man-is-to-womanizer-as-woman-is-to-what)

Comment: And [**An English expression for 'femme fatale'**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171313/an-english-expression-for-femme-fatale) .

Comment: @BeansnLeaves You're right. Fixed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I voted to close as a dupe of *"Man" is to "womanizer" as "woman" is to what?*. The top and accepted answer there has the most common term IMO and the one which immediately occurred to me: **maneater** (also *vamp*, which is cute).

Comment: The ability to capture a prey (chase after a man/woman) is not a skill it is an **art**, i.e [The art of seduction](https://www.google.it/search?q=The+art+of+seduction&oq=The+art+of+seduction&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22The+art+of+seduction%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: Four votes to close this question, you should reword or recast this post and show some *serious* research (for once). I am adding my VTC now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Flirt" comes to mind.  Actually, a whole bunch of phrases/terms come to mind but they would descend in to the "derogatory" category and, as such, wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

Temptress

temptress
ˈtɛm(p)trɪs/
noun
a woman who tempts someone to do something, typically a sexually attractive woman who sets out to allure or seduce someone.(Source:Google.com)

Comment: along the same lines: seductress

Answer (score 0):

Many of the words for sexual behavior have cultural prejudices built in, so I think many nouns and adjectives are already going to stack the cards against you. "Flirty," "Promiscuous," and "Temptress," read like euphemisms for loose behavior. I'd look for phrases. If you're looking for a word for a woman who actively dates around, enjoys the company of men, but isn't a tease, consider,

**dating around**:

> He was a good guy. Not sure why I was so sure of that. Maybe it was a
>   skill that I developed when I was *dating around*.

**man-chaser**, used wryly:

> He was a good guy. Not sure why I was so sure of that. Maybe it was a
>   skill that I developed when I was *chasing men*.

these seem like a better fit, especially since the woman in question has dated "good" men and good men don't usually go for flirty, flighty, teasing, temptresses.

*sources:* dictionary.com, myself.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, most of these answers are pretty judgmental. Simply referring to the lady in question as a "***single-girl/gal***" would imply that she *"chased"* men, without casting aspersions at her character.

(A single woman who does not chase men is known as a/an "old-maid", "spinster", "cat-person" or, lesbian.)

Answer (score -1):

*He was a good guy. Not sure why I was so sure of that. Maybe it was a skill that I developed when I was [**sowing my wild oats**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oat).*

> Go through a period of wild or promiscuous behaviour while young:
>
> *he sowed his wild oats before settling down*

Your hunt for a single word notwithstanding, this is how I'd put it. It isn't offensive (on the contrary, it can be humorous).

EDIT: In my opinion, the expression can be used by a girl. Though etymologically it looks like it's restricted to men, as @Janus pointed out.

In any case, I'd let my female character use it.

For a single word, consider the one in the definition: [promiscuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promiscuous#promiscuous__2).

Comment: Uh, hmm, you don't think *planting seed* is connotative of men?

Comment: @DanBron: I don't think anything in English is restrictive to men anymore, including the word `man` :)

Comment: Well, *man* has a very long history of not being restricted to XYs; *that*, at least, is not a new thing!

Comment: @TusharRaj The word _man_ has **never** been restricted to males. Its original meaning was ‘human being’, and it has kept that meaning for millennia; the secondary development of ‘human’ → ‘male human’ is a later one. _Sowing one’s wild oats_, however, is a direct analogy to sowing seed, putting one’s seed in fertile ground, etc.—all metaphoric descriptions of the exclusively male part of coitus. See also [World Wide Words’ piece](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sow1.htm) on the expression.

Comment: @DanBron: Besides, even if it is, the context makes it clear. I'm assuming Jano needs it for his novel. Writers have more licence than usual in these matters.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Man, dude, guy... the list goes on. I think the readers wouldn't mind if a girl used this expression. Some girls might mind if you say they can't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That was an interesting article! Thanks for the link. Tushar, sure, it's a good answer, I just quibbled with the "not restricted to men" part; I think Jano should be aware there's a small risk in that usage. Why do you say *restrictive* rather than *restricted*, by the way?

Comment: @TusharRaj But I would guess more girls would mind if a man used it about them (which would be the case here, even though the narrator is female). Also, I've never heard _dude_ or _guy_ used to refer to a woman directly (nor _man_, for that matter).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think the narrator is talking about having relationships with men. So, in this case, men were the 'victims'. I'm saying girls could mind if you say that they can only be on the wrong end of this expression.

Comment: "in the fast lane".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: [Guys](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/19078/77339) is not restrictive. Males and females both can say to another female something like 'Not cool, man/dude/bro'. But we're digressing here. All I'm saying is that a female character could use the expression without everyone getting all worked up about it.

Comment: (Side note, but worth pointing out that Jano is seeking a noun, not a verb or adjective.)

Comment: @DanBron: I might be wrong, but I thought his need for the absence of negative connotations was more pressing than the need for a noun.

Comment: @DanBron: Also, if girls can [have balls](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%27s+got+balls%2Che%27s+got+balls&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20%27s%20got%20balls%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20%27s%20got%20balls%3B%2Cc0), why can't they have seeds :)

Comment: Thank nGram link doesn't work for me :( (PS: *sowing one's wild oats* frequently does have negative connotations, but you're right that it can be used in a way that frames the subject positively. The link Janus provided has more details on the negative aspects; in short, it's not about promiscuity, it's about frivolity.)

Comment: @DanBron: Dunno why the ngram doesn't work. It was this search: `she 's got balls,he's got balls`. Good catch on the `restricted` error. Thanks. And I've only ever seen this `wild oats` used in the context of promiscuity. Never frivolity.

Comment: No, I meant the "negative connotations" of SOWO are related to the subject *wasting his time* (sleeping around), rather that doing something productive. It's a dig at his work ethic, not sexual ethics.

Comment: @DanBron: Oh. Got it now.