# An English or French word that summarizes 'A very attractive or seductive looking woman'

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

I'm looking for a word (English or French) which summarizes 'A very attractive or seductive looking woman'. Also looking for a word or term that explains the Women Beauty.

Edit: Out of my research, I found that the word 'Peach' also means 'A very attractive or seductive looking woman'. I would like to find out is there any other word that gives the same meaning.

In short, a word that refers a beautiful and attractive woman.

Comment: @Weather Vane Off-topic. _A_ femme fatale.

Comment: @Weather Vane But that question should not be answered here.

Comment: Note that I have no idea what the last sentence in the question means. What is *the Women Beauty*? Where have you heard this phrase? It's new to me I can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I moved the (amended and filled out) comment to a proper answer.

Comment: All the suggestions that follow at this time, and many others, have been suggested at the duplicate-or-is-it [An English expression for femme fatale](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171313/an-english-expression-for-femme-fatale/171315#171315)

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth, 
Thanks for your response. I just read the referred question that you suggested as a duplicate. But I still feel what I am looking for is something different.

Comment: All I would like to know is, a word that refers to a very attractive women, I came across a meaning for the word 'Peach - A very attractive or seductive looking woman'. Is there any alternative with the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Temptress

I suggest this in the vein of pre-raphaelite paintings of gorgeous sexy women who have a carefree attitude to their voluptousness and (mythically!) evoke almost out-of control responses in others, such is the passion that they arouse.   Yet a true ‘temptress’ doesn’t care or is oblivious to such reactions - she’s just being herself.

Whereas dictionaries miss the original, romantic, point, of the temptress, in my view, and describe such ‘temptresses’ in pejorative terms such as ‘she uses her female charm to attract people sexually‘ which demotes the temptress considerably.

Anyway, temptress.  A women in possession of her sexual power and power of attraction.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/temptress

Answer (score 1):

[**Enchantress**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchantress):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : a fascinating or beautiful woman

The definition includes *beautiful*, which can be synonymous with *attractive*, and a woman who is fascinating can also be seductive.

Used in a sentence, you might say:

> I couldn't stop looking at her. She was a real *enchantress*.

---

This is also helped by the other sense of *enchantress*:

> **1** : a woman who practices magic : SORCERESS

In a figurative sense, you could say that a beautiful and alluring woman has *cast a spell* on you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **femme fatale** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/femme_fatale) says

> **femme fatale**
>   NOUN
>
> An attractive and seductive woman, especially one who will ultimately cause distress to a man who becomes involved with her.
>
> *She is the femme fatale whose seductive voice, glamorous hair, and voluptuous body Rita Hayworth lent to the screen in 1946.*

This phrase, however, has overtones of impending disaster.

Comment: That was my first thought, too.