# Another meaning of the vulgar word "slut"

Tags: british-english, word-usage, offensive-language, dictionaries

I guess people who speak American and Philippine English will unanimously agree that the word "slut" is a very offensive term referring to a promiscuous woman. However, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slut?show=0&t=1392481410) and [Oxford Advanced Learner's](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/slut) also attach another meaning to the word--a slovenly woman--and this is supposedly chiefly British.

slut:  a lazy, careless, or slovenly woman :  slattern (that slut of a housekeeper — Margaret Kennedy) --Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

To speakers of British English: how often would one use the word "slut" in reference to a messy or untidy woman? Is this usage current or obsolescent?

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia's entry for [slut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slut)?

Comment: Ha! It also used to mean "servant girl"-- "an admirable slut" who "pleases us mightily, doing more service than both the others and deserves wages better" (February 1664). Goodness gracious!

Comment: As a British English speaker, I believe it is only used as an offensive term for a promiscuous woman, unless you are a certain UKIP MP.

Comment: @sweeneyrod I think you mean MEP... surely we don't have any UKIP in Westminster?

Comment: I thought this was one of the better ELU questions of late; I hoped it wouldn't be sidetracked into some silly debate. To me, there's no "right" or "wrong" way to use the word; the question is just an earnest inquiry about usage, which in this case seems to vary some based on geography and generation. On this side of the Atlantic, someone from my generation would instantly know that, "Fumble, you ignorant slut" would be meant only as a good-natured allusion to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekend_Update#Jane_Curtin_.281976.E2.80.931980.29) cultural reference.

Comment: @J.R.: Before looking into it and answering, I was only vaguely aware that some people associate *slut* more with *promiscuous* that others. I'd seen the recent hoo-hah about Bloom, but just assumed everyone was annoyed by his flippant/rude "sexism" re women being slovenly cleaners. The idea that anyone would even *think* there was a suggestion of loose sexual morals in that context frankly never occurred to me. But I now realise many (Americans?) *only* understand the word that way. And Bloom *was* talking in an "international" context (MEPs), after all. A worse gaffe that it first appeared!

Answer (score 13):

I'm British - and definitely getting to be the wrong side of "middle-aged", which may have a bearing. But so far as I'm concerned, ***slut*** primarily means the first definition in OED...

> *- a woman of dirty, slovenly, or untidy habits or appearance*

Nor do I disagree with their second definition...

> *- a woman of a low or loose character; a bold or impudent girl; a hussy, jade*

That second definition *could* include anything from a woman who (provocatively or carelessly) shows more bare flesh than is proper, to one who indulges in casual sex more often than most.

But I personally would *never* extend it to mean *"a women who trades sex for money"* except where all the above attributes applied anyway, and were more relevant to my context.

---

But all such words have not only an inherent range of meanings *in and of themselves;* different people have widely differing value judgements concerning cleanliness, tidiness, sexuality, etc. Not to mention which there are the figurative and facetious usages. Many a male has been accused of [*whoring himself to*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22whoring%20himself%20to%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22whoring%20himself%20to%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7701j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) [whatever the writer disapproves of].

Use of sexually-loaded terms is also significantly influenced by "publicly-acknowledged morality", as portrayed in the media, and that can vary widely by country. I've recently watched several American "Coming-of-age / High school/college" movies. It took me a while to realise that in *that* context, blow-jobs are usually seen as "normal, heavy petting", whereas penetrative sex is usually classed as "whoring" regardless of whether anyone actually *paid* for it. That's Hollywood for you. British movies don't often feature oral sex - but if they *do,* it's more like "getting to *fourth* base" (where third base is intercourse).

---

EDIT: I prefaced this answer by pointing out that it's only a *British* perspective (which is what OP asked for anyway). But my gut feeling was that younger Brits don't even use *slut* - they use *slag* for "promiscuous female *or* male", and *slob* for "untidy/dirty/lazy person" (again, *unisex*).

Google NGrams appears to support my feeling. Check [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slut&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1;,slut;,c0) to see how *slut* has steadily risen in the AmE corpus in recent decades (switch to the BrE corpus and you'll see a corresponding *fall*). And check [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%27s%20a%20slag&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,she%20%27s%20a%20slag;,c0) to see how *she's a slag* has gained currency in the BrE corpus (switch to the AmE corpus to see that Americans simply don't use that word often enough to chart usage at all).

It may therefore be true that on the relatively few occasions when younger Brits *do* come across *slut* in their native land, they might tend to ascribe it the modern American sense - simply because that's the one they're most likely to have encountered through international media, movies, etc.

Comment: There you go! Merriam-Webster isn't entirely wrong after all! :-) But would you say this sense is becoming outdated?

Comment: @Louel: I can't answer for Americans and Philippinos. I would say the *word* is becoming outdated in the UK. My children and their contemporaries might use *slag* for a slovenly person (often with the implication of loose morals as well as dirty/untidy), but I don't think they use *slut* at all (except when facetiously echoing their parents' usage). If you're sure people in your area use it to mean *whore*, you can reasonably do the same *there*. Just don't expect that sense to be the first thing that comes to mind if you're speaking to a Brit.

Comment: Hollywood has many sins to answer for, but I think its depiction of sexual behavior is following rather driving social practice in this country.

Comment: @StoneyB: You'd know better than me what goes on on campus, I suppose. But I'd say Hollywood is definitely not in the business of *educating and informing* - they're in the business of *making money*, which on the "sexuality" front would normally mean *exciting people's interest, turning them on*. Hell - even daytime soaps don't usually reflect what their target audience are normally doing (slobbing out on the sofa watching daytime soaps). And Hollywood is obviously more "escapist/unreal" than that.

Comment: Doubtless; but even in the 60s oral sex was regarded among my peers more as a 'safe' substitute for penetrative sex  than as an exotic supplement to it. Cisatlantically, by the way, *slut* is never synonymous with *slattern*, *whore* is more likely to mean socially rather than commercially active (a prostitute is a 'pro' or 'hooker'). Conversely, however, both *slut* and *whore* are freely used for compensated non-sexual activity: *He's such an attention whore*, meaning he engages in whatever activity will earn him attention.

Comment: Probably a generational thing. Godfrey Bloom got into trouble for this [recently](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-24222992). He claimed he meant meaning 1. Not sure how many people believed him or were even aware of this meaning.

Comment: @Martin: The Bloom thing is just politics. Given the exact context, anyone who seriously thinks he actually *intended* the "loose sexual morals" sense would have to be soft in the head. After all, he did use the word in the same breath as saying he wanted to *"deal with women's issues because I just don't think they clean behind the fridge enough"*. As to the "generational" thing - as I said earlier, all the under-30s I know tend to say *slag*, not *slut*. So maybe if they *do* hear it, they pick up of the US sense (which isn't even *mentioned* in current OED).

Comment: (apropos which, I will edit the answer on this point)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I seriously doubt that anyone under a certain age even has heard of the definition you believe to be primary myself. I would regard the terms slut and slag as being used largely interchangeably when I have come across them. Might not be quite obsolete now but certainly I can't imagine many people using it in the more innocuous sense for risk of being misunderstood.

Comment: @Martin: We seem to be rather going round in circles here. But it wouldn't surprise me if one of the reasons younger Brits don't use ***slut*** is precisely *because* their parents still use it in the "original" sense. I'm in no doubt that until 20-30 years ago, it was always more common in the UK than the US. You can check the relative prevalence values in the NGrams to confirm that, even allowing for the fact that NGrams often have a lot of misattributions re the US/UK split.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I seriously doubt that theory but without an opinion poll who knows! Googling "slut slag" I see the following UK items in the first page [I'd much rather be a slag than a slut](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/oct/06/rather-be-slag-than-slut) (author seems unaware of definition 1). [Difference between slut and slag](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1045983) conclusion on the forum "none"

Comment: @Martin: Believe what you like. At least it's a credible *explanation* for the unmistakable fact that (primarily *British*) OED doesn't list the current US definition, *and* the fact that it's only US not UK usage where *slut* has increased dramatically in recent decades. And Google Books/NGrams covers *millions* of written texts - a few items in individual forums might mean very little (on the whole Internet there are always a few more making the opposite point). *And* Google page rankings are dominated by US surfers - so Brits see what Yanks think, not vice-versa.

Comment: This is a column in the Guardian (UK paper) and a co.uk website. They weren't cherry picked just the first couple of results I saw of relevance.

Comment: @Martin: Now we're *definitely* going round in circles. I just said Google results are skewed because page rankings are dominated by US surfers. And one female columnist deliberately trying to stir up controversy looks a bit silly considering she'd been invited to speak at [Slut Night](http://www.run-riot.com/think/slut-night-other-club) *a cabaret-style conversation about what it means to be a “slut”*, covering, among other things, *the **reappropriation** of the word “slut”*. I didn't go, obviously, but I'd assume "reappropriation" there means "recovering **our** meaning for the word".

Comment: Well we are clearly going round in circles so I'll leave it at that. I don't see any support for your theory that *younger Brits don't use slut ... precisely because their parents still use it in the "original" sense.* from other native British speakers that have participated in this question so far though.

Comment: I have heard many younger Brits (teenagers and twenty-odds) use _slut_, though never in the slovenly sense. ‘Someone who has loose sexual morals’ is not what it commonly means, though: ‘someone who has many sexual partners’ is much closer. It is not always (in fact, less and less) a derogatory term—and it refers equally to male and female specimens. Possibly even more commonly to guys, since having multiple sexual partners is still somewhat stigmatised for girls

Comment: As an 18 year old English male I can confirm that we 'young ones' do use the term slut, but not enough to be classified as frequent usage of the term. Slag is probably more prevalent, but I couldn't make any guesses as to why without more research into its past usage.

Comment: @Janus: I recall discussing "unisex" *slag* with my 23-year-old son a couple of years ago when he said a (male) friend of his was *a bit of a slag*. I don't recall the word *slut* coming up then (or anywhen else, come to that) with the "younger generation". But I'm pretty sure my 83-years old mother once (facetiously) said something like *"You're a slob and she's a slut, so you should both be very comfortable together"* about me and my then "partner". She just meant we're not very "houseproud", obviously - nothing about sexual morals or behaviour.

Comment: @Pharap: But are you/were you aware that older people use the word differently? My *theory* (I hesitate to even put it that strongly; it's just an idea I thought *might* be relevant) is that you might avoid it partly to avoid the embarrassment of possible misunderstandings.

Comment: @Louel It's almost certainly going to become outdated because there's far more Americans using it than Britons, and the Americans use the 'promiscuous' meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was indeed aware of its alternate meaning, but I thought it was more of a regional difference than a generational one. Personally I just don't use the word much because I either don't have cause to or there are other words that I would use instead. Generally I don't go around speaking ill without cause, and if I have cause it's usually enough cause to resort straight to swearing. Again, there may be regional or individual differences at work, it's hard to say without research or more experience of other regions.

Comment: @Pharap: Wise words indeed. But I don't see any signs yet that Brits are about to adopt "fanny" as meaning [back] bottom rather than "front bottom". Nor are we about to give up having a fag after dinner just because it makes Americans snigger, and our cars still have bonnets and boots, not hoods and trunks. British English ain't about to lie down and die just because of the weight of numbers over there (who increasingly speak Spanish rather than "American" anyway! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed - those words are unlikely to die, I am however less hopeful for 'slut'. Bonnet, boot and fag are all still in common usage, whereas fanny is less commonly used (more because of its meaning than anything else) but I'm lead to believe it's still quite common in Scotland and some parents do teach it to their children, particularly when they are made aware of the American variant. Slut on the other hand has very little usage as, like I say, there are many alternatives that are more desirable. It's definitely in a minority though, British English isn't dying any time soon.

Comment: I feel like I should add my voice to the masses on this one, just to say that I'm British, 23, grew up in the south, and to me the word "slut" has no implications of *"a woman of dirty, slovenly, or untidy habits or appearance"*; it only has the second meaning given by this answer. "Slag" is also widely used, but I'm not sure if it's more common than "slut", and it's definitely not true that the word "slut" is becoming outdated in Britain or that "young people don't user it", at least not where I'm from. Just wanted to clear that up.

Answer (score 6):

You can act or look like a *slut* in as much as your manner of dress, makeup, and behaviour suggests that you are on the lookout for a man, any man, because you want or need the confirmation that you are sexually attractive. In this case, a *slut* (technically speaking) is not, and never is a prostitute, but a promiscuous woman or one who at the very least gives that impression.

If a woman is *slutty* or *sluttish*, it could mean her appearance is slovenly, her makeup carelessly applied, her hair unkempt, but only because in the collective imaginary, people tend to associate cheap bright red lipstick, caked mascara, and holey fishnet tights (pantyhose in the US) with sluttish behaviour.

I don't think I have ever heard a woman being described as being a slut if she was generally untidy or unkempt. The word I would hear most often, in those instances, would be a *slob*.

---

### EDIT 1

I'm going to play the British card now myself. I was born in London and lived there until I was a teenager, and I regularly go back to London for visits and short holidays. I was familiar with the term, slut, before moving to Italy circa 30 years ago, for me it's a well-established word whose meaning I have described above. The first definition may be found more often in books, which probably explains why the OED lists it as being first. However, [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slut?q=slut), and  The [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/slut) both state that *slut* is:

> 1a) a woman who has many casual sexual partners

and list it as their *first definition*.

I'm certain that British native speakers today are more familiar with that definition than with its more dated one; a woman whose general appearance is unclean. I looked for references to back my gut reaction, and I looked for how the word is used today in speech, not in works of literature. I thought of The Daily Mail, a British online newspaper, right-wing, an unreliable source if one is looking for objectivity in the news  but an excellent one to witness how the English language is developing. The earliest reference to *slut* I found in a piece dated **o9/o3/2001**, entitled [Born Romantic](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-29285/Born-Romantic.html)

> British effort of the week is Born Romantic, a comedy about various
> young Londoners who frequent a salsa club. There's a well-spoken bitch
> (Olivia Williams), a mousy, morbid neurotic (Catherine McCormack in
> spectacles) and **a rampant slut** (Jane Horrocks).
>
> They are pursued, in a
> way that's hard to distinguish from sexual harassment, by a charmless,
> married Scotsman (Craig Ferguson), a pathetic, incompetent mugger
> (Jimi Mistry) and a self-pitying, *slobbish* Scouser (David Morrissey).

I strongly doubt that The Daily Mail would use a term which their readers would largely be unaware of or might confuse it for meaning an *unclean, slovenly woman*. The comedy, by the way and its actors are/were all British too.

I include here the Daily Mail link showing the results for "slut" starting from the [most relevant](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/search.html?pageOffset=&pageSize=&sel=site&searchPhrase=slut&orderBy=relevDesc&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_channelshortname=on&_contenttype=on&_contenttype=on&dateupdated=&dateFrom=&dateTo=&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_authornamef=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on&_personnames=on).  Probably there are some pieces where women are criticized for their laziness and called *sluts*, probably AmEng has influenced as to how the younger British speakers interpret the word today; I don't doubt it for a second, but I'm convinced that nowadays British speakers are largely unaware of its original meaning - "*c.1400, "a dirty, slovenly, or untidy woman*"

---

### EDIT 2

I wish I had come across this answer posted several months earlier, further proof that nowadays British people tend to associate loose sexual behaviour with the term *slut*. This post I found purely by chance, but when I read the answer it reminded me of this question. All emphases are mine.

The user was answering the question *[“Man” is to “womanizer” as “woman” is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/man-is-to-womanizer-as-woman-is-to-what)*

> Please excuse me if you find these terms profane but, *my grandmother*
> would refer to woman who chases men as a **slut**, although this is
> sometimes used to describe a girl as dirty or messy. I do recall a man
> using the term to describe another who was especially open and active
> in her choice of bedfellows. [...]

<sup>[Jodrell](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69185/44619) May 28 '12.  His [profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11537/jodrell) states he is from the UK</sup>

Comment: I haven't actually seen *Born Romantic*, but knowing Jane Horrocks I'd think she's more likely to play a "bold or impudent hussy" than a *whore/slag*. Appetite whetted, I'll look out for it. But certainly the first two newspaper items in your final link are using *slut* to mean *woman who dresses provocatively*, not *woman who has indiscriminate sex*. Essentially, I think you have not proven your case at all.

Comment: The first sentence says: *You can act or look like a slut in as much as your manner of dress...*

Answer (score 4):

This may not be an answer to your question, but some interesting trivia.

I'm a German native speaker and we have the word "Schlampe", which accurately translates to [slut](http://www.dict.cc/?s=slut). The corresponding adjective to "Schlampe" is ["schlampig"](http://www.dict.cc/?s=schlampig).
Interestingly enough, "schlampig" has two different meanings, that correlate with your question:

- *schlampig* as in sluttish.
- *schlampig* as in slovenly, messy, filthy.

In German these two meanings are still implied today. You have to guess by the context, which meaning is the correct. Nevertheless, "Schlampe" and "schlampig" is always offensive.
This makes it plausible, that the double-meaning of "slut" dates back even further than previously thought of.

In medieval and pre-medieval times "sluts" were most likely the lowest class of the society. They were linked to filth and diseases. Therefore the bonding of the two meanings seems logical.

The theory of a Germanic origin is supported by [this Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slut).

Comment: I never noticed that "schlampig" ("slutty" auf English) is so close to the extremely vulgar "slam pig".

Comment: I never noticed that "slam pig" is a thing. :D

Answer (score 3):

It must be more than obsolescent in that context. It would be *obsolete*. I have not heard it used in the UK.

Comment: You haven't specified "age" on your profile, but I wouldn't be surprised to find it's under 30. I've just added what I see as supporting evidence in my own answer for my sense that younger Brits don't use the word so much anyway (making the whole question somewhat academic, if not [*moot!*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96435/the-point-is-moot) :)

Answer (score 3):

I can remember once hearing someone who would now being in her early 30s using the word in this sense (about 10 years ago, so she would then have been in her early 20s). Her use was facetious, but when I asked her about it (because I am after all the sort of person who is interested in words), and she said that she had grown up thinking of the word primarily in the original "unkempt, slovenly" sense, but considered herself unusual in this; that it was more a matter of her ideolect based on family use than a common opinion.

More generally, I would say that among younger English-speakers in Britain and Ireland, not only would the original sense not be the primary one, but some may not even be aware of it at all. I've certainly heard it used, but generally with a tone that suggested people considered it obsolete, and often deliberately joking on the primary meaning being related to sex.

Of course, the reason the word has both senses, is from the two traits being conflated; assuming that a woman who does not keep a tidy house or is untidy in her personal appearance would have "loose sexual morals", which is an opinion less likely to be held, in a whole variety of ways. (Personally, whenever I've engaged in "loose sexual morals" with a woman, they've tended to get dressed up a bit first, YMMV).

Comment: Out of interest, which area of the UK was this woman from?

Comment: @Pharap she wasn't, she was from Ireland. Irish English tends to be close to British English but with a few syntactical differences (not relevant here), a few additions (not relevant here) and a few retentions that are also found in some, but not all, of the UK (relevant here, as my only ever hearing one such use adds to my conclusion that it's now a rarity).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Webster is wrong since it says: *"First Known Use: 15th century"*. But actual etymology says it's existed since the 14th century, according to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=slut&searchmode=none).

Comment: The source you linked doesn't contradict Webster - it appears to _agree_. The Online Etymology Dictionary doesn't say this word has existed since the 14th century, it says circa 1400. The century from 1400-1500 is the 15th century, so the two sources are stating roughly the same thing (give or take a small number of decades, hence the 'circa'). The only pre-_15c_ definition in your link, from the 14th century, describes an unclean _man_, so whilst the word might have existed, we don't have evidence for the current meaning being used that way yet.

Comment: This doesn't even answer OP's *Is this usage current or obsolescent?*, let alone the matter of what sense would normally be intended or understood.

Comment: I have an edition for children of selected Grimm's fairy tales, given to my father in 1918. In one story a girl, punished for being idle and selfish by having pitch poured over her, is described as a 'dirty slut'. Obviously the word would not have been used in a children's book if its meaning was ambiguous then.

Answer (score 0):

Just an interesting alternative usage:  we used it to mean "took from someone not quite by stealing, but more by asking without waiting for permission."

As an example:  "John slutted one of my beers!  He just walked up, said, 'Hey!  Beer!' and took one!"

This may be entirely the dialect of my fraternity house when I was in college, though.